# Numpy memmap and multiple processes

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

Can't understand the behaviour of threads in python. I was interesting about thread safety of np.memmap(), and wrote some example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import time

mm = np.memmap("foo", dtype=int, mode = "w+", shape = (10,))

def foo(i):
    while True:
        mm[1]=np.random.randint(low=2, high=50)
        sleepfor = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.1, size=None)
        print "proces = ", i, " value = ", mm[1], " sleep = ", sleepfor

        time.sleep(sleepfor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    p1 = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
    p1.start() 

    p2 = Process(target=foo, args=(2,))
    p2.start()

    p3 = Process(target=foo, args=(3,))
    p3.start()

    p4 = Process(target=foo, args=(4,))
    p4.start()
```

It outputs this:

```
proces =  1  value =  13  sleep =  0.91652869794
proces =  2  value =  13  sleep =  0.91652869794
proces =  3  value =  13  sleep =  0.91652869794
proces =  4  value =  13  sleep =  0.91652869794
proces =  1  value =  6  sleep =  0.721062383299
proces =  2  value =  6  sleep =  0.721062383299
proces =  3  value =  6  sleep =  0.721062383299
proces =  4  value =  6  sleep =  0.721062383299
proces =  1  value =  24  sleep =  0.161040327399
proces =  2  value =  24  sleep =  0.161040327399
proces =  3  value =  24  sleep =  0.161040327399
proces =  4  value =  24  sleep =  0.161040327399
proces =  1  value =  22  sleep =  0.837121791675
proces =  2  value =  22  sleep =  0.837121791675
proces =  3  value =  22  sleep =  0.837121791675
proces =  4  value =  22  sleep =  0.837121791675
and so on...
```

Why random values are the same for different processes?

Why they change every 4 iterations?

And also how to write a test to check if numpy memmap is thread safe (is it?)

UPD:

Ok, random.seed() solves issue number one and number two?
Then I commented sleep() to cause writing concurrency and also no errors occured. Does it mean that np.memmap() thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with `np.random`, although I do not know why.
If you use `mm[1] = random.randint(1, 20)` instead it fixes the problem of the value being the same across all of the processes.

```
>>> proces =  1  value =  17  sleep =  0.0967840686219
>>> proces =  2  value =  13  sleep =  0.0967840686219
>>> proces =  3  value =  19  sleep =  0.0967840686219
>>> proces =  4  value =  14  sleep =  0.0967840686219
```

Using `random.random` also fixes the same problem for the `sleep` variable.

Comment: Sorry, why the down vote?

Comment: I did not vote. Its not me.

Comment: So values are ok. But I tried to make sleep the same way . It is steel the same.

Comment: Thats because it is still using np.random. Try changing to random.random() or something similar

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: Of course I changed to raandint - the same result